# Android: parse query in thread

Tags: android, multithreading, wait, program-entry-point, synchronized

I'm using the Parse library to query some records from DB that will be shown in a ListView with a custom adapter. I've a table with records and each record should I do a counting query from other table.

This is the thread for the counting query of each object retrieved:

```
getVisualizations = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < events.size(); i++) {
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(ParseConstant.PT_VISUALIZ);
                query.whereEqualTo(ParseConstant.PT_VISUALIZ_EVENTO, events.get(i));

                events.get(i).setVisualizations(query.count());
            }
        }
    });
```

> events is an Object ArrayList

And this is the code in the main

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(ParseConstant.PT_EVENT);
    query.setLimit(30);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> resultList, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {

                events = new ArrayList<Event>();

                for (int i = 0; i < resultList.size(); i++) {
                    Event event = (Event) resultList.get(i);

                    events.add(event);
                }

                if (!getVisualizations.isAlive()) {

                    getVisualizations.start();

                }

                if (adapter != null) {
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    adapter = new AdapterEvent(getActivity(), R.layout.list_event, events, list);
                    AnimationAdapter animAdapter = new SwingBottomInAnimationAdapter(adapter);
                    animAdapter.setAbsListView(list);
                    list.setAdapter(animAdapter);
                }

                loadingBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            } else {
                Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

The problem is that after the thread has started, I don't know how to block the main thread  until the other thread finish. (Sorry for the english :/ )

Comment: I recomend you to use the class AsyncTask to do thread process. And the main thread shouldn't be blocked, because is the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you should use Thread.join() - if we are dealing with 2 threads, this will block one thread, while allowing the other to complete, then once it does complete, it will resume. Here is a [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/simple.html) on it